# Where can I find and watch Black Butler Season 3 Episode 1 legally online?

Tags: resources, black-butler

I keep hearing people say 'I watched black butler season 3 first episode' and I want to know if there is a **legal site** online where I can watch Episode 1.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @アズーサ, [Hulu is streaming Season 3](http://www.hulu.com/search?q=Black%20Butler%3A%20Book%20of%20Circus)

You can also watch it on [Funimation's Site](http://www.funimation.com/shows/black-butler/videos)

[CrunchyRoll have also got the series for streaming](http://www.crunchyroll.com/black-butler-book-of-circus). (Without English subtitles for the moment however)

Season 3 or "Book of Circus" has only started releasing (July 11, 2014) at the time of writing, so there's no physical product to buy. Perhaps someone will pick it up once the season is over.

Comment: Does anime streamed on Hulu normally get physical release? i know Madman released physical copies of the first 2 seasons of Black Butler but i don't know if they were streamed on Hulu and i can't name a single anime that Hulu streamed which i can buy

Comment: I think usually streaming and physical release licenses are sold separately, according to the last reddit crunchroll CEO ama they are anyway